# How to enforce pairing method PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN?

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I'm trying to pair with BLE device by ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST broadcast receiver but always receive PAIRING_VARIANT_DISPLAY_PASSKEY pairing type instead of PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN i expected. How can i change it to PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN? My remote device don't have display i have no idea why it using display passkey by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both devices tell each other their own input/output capabilities. Based on that the Bluetooth standard defines which pairing variant should be used on each device.

So if your peripheral device doesn't have a display, but has a keyboard, then it's logical that the Android device shows the passkey and that passkey is supposed to be input on your peripheral device.

Comment: So there is no way to enforce entering pin on android side? I used windows BLE stack before and it works.

Comment: Thanks again, i resolved my issue. The problem was in peripheral device which one declared keyboard only capabilities but actually has no keyboard and enters static pin via his api. This is obviously against BLE standard as you  described. SAD!